# How to use JQuery to Disable "specific" Dropdowns

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

My Goal: Checking radio button will disable the 'same' column of dropdownlist in a number of separate tables.

I understand you can assign ID's and act on those ID's, or using by Tag Name.  However, I am new to ASP and have a unique situation that neither of these options appear at the surface to work for me.

I have a web form, that has multiple sections.  Each section is made up of a Table with 3 columns and X amount of rows.  The first column is used for asking a question, the second and third column reference the left and right side of the body and have a dropdownlist of answers in each column:

Example

```
 <asp:ContentGroup ID="contentgroup1" runat="server" Title="Sometitle">
<table id="Table1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-indent: 20px">
             Do you feel pain:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server" TabIndex="601">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown2" runat="server" TabIndex="701">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:ContentGroup ID="contentgroup2" runat="server" Title="Sometitle">
<table id="Table2" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-indent: 20px">
             Do you feel numbness?
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown3" runat="server" TabIndex="601">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown4" runat="server" TabIndex="701">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I obviously can't do something like

```
var x = document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTagName("select");
var y = document.getElementById('table2').getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Or I would would be working with all the dropdownlist .  I know classes don't have to be unique, would that be the only approach - to assign a "class='left'" to all the  for the left column and a "right" class for all the columns on the right and perform some JavaScript on each class?

Goal: There will be a radio button designated for the "Left side" and one for the "Right side". Selecting a radio button will disable the appropriate column of dropdownlist in all the tables on the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

So to access all the left hand drop downs in your first table you could do:

```
$('#Table1 tr td:nth-child(2) select');
```

and the right hand drop downs:

```
$('#Table1 tr td:nth-child(3) select');

// or a special case of nth-child: last-child:
$('#Table1 tr td:last-child select');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using JQuery, you could use CSS selectors to select specific columns of your table.  Since you say that the `select` elements should be disabled in multiple tables if one of the radio buttons is clicked, I would give each of your tables a class, for example `<table class="disable-columns"></table>`.  Then use that class name in conjunction with JQuery's excellent CSS selector support to select the `select` elements in the middle column of your tables

```
var leftDropDownLists = $("table.disable-columns tr td:first-child + td select");
```

And to select the `select` elements in the third column

```
var rightDropDownLists = $("table.disable-columns tr td:firstchild + td + td select");
```

You can go here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html for documentation on different CSS selectors available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think you're looking for.

[jsfiddle.net/CJSwK](http://jsfiddle.net/CJSwK/)

Answer (score 0):

Give your radio buttons IDs and then you can do something like this:

```
$('#rightRadioButtonId').click(function() { 
    $('table1 select').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('table2 select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#leftRadioButtonId').click(function() { 
    $('table1 select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('table2 select').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: You don't want to give the same ID to more than one HTML element in a page.  An ID should be unique to one element.  A class would do what you're suggesting, however.

Comment: Radio buttons are separate entities and can have different IDs.

Comment: Tell me I am wrong, but wouldn't this cause all the "select" statements in each table to be disabled or enabled and not specific <td> in a column?

Comment: Oh, oops, I misunderstood what you were trying to do here.  Wow, completely.  Actually, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Are `table1` and `table2` supposed to be classes?  I assume that you are using them in the same manner that he is using them (as IDs for each table).  In that case, this would disable or enable all of the selects in the respective table, which he specifically said he didn't want.

Comment: @pghtech I think you're right.  This is pretty much the exact situation you described after saying, "So I obviously can't do something like..."  Of course, you could add a "left-column" and "right-column" class to each `<td>` (or `<select>`) in each of your tables, but it's unnecessary if you just use CSS selectors.